# Where did Icon Composer go from Xcode?

Tags: macos, xcode, icon

I can't seem to find Icon Composer on the Xcode versions at run on Mountain Lion.

[image]

Where is it? Has it been taken out? How to get it back?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It's been moved into one of the add-on packages for Xcode, and is now part of the **Graphics Tools for Xcode** package.

Apparently this is (at least partly?) because this is no longer the 'officially recommended' way to generate (high resolution) icons. See the [OS X Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000967-SW1) and the [High Resolution Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Optimizing/Optimizing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012302-CH7-SW2) for more info.

I believe Icon Composer doesn't support the highest resolution icons required these days (1024x1024), and you're encouraged to use `iconutil` instead, which does, and allows you to convert between ICNS and "iconsets" (effectively just a folder containing a collection of PNG files of different resolutions).

---

If you still want it, you can get it as follows:

In Xcode, go to the **Xcode** > **Open Developer Tool** > **More Developer tools...**.

You'll need to log in (or register) with your (free) Apple Developer account, and then you'll be shown a list of available packages for Xcode, including the Graphics Tools for Xcode. Grab the latest one and install.

This DMG of Graphics Tools contains:

- CI Filter Browser
- **Icon Composer**
- OpenGL Driver Monitor
- OpenGL Profiler
- OpenGL Shader Builder
- Pixie
- Quartz Composer
- Quartz Composer Visualizer
- Quartz Debug

Comment: Actually you are mistaken. Icon Composer in its latest version does support the 1024x1024 size. Just go to the menubar and go to view > Show 1024x1024 or click the 1024x1024 button at the bottom of the window. I have made icons with that size before.

Comment: I found the answers above useful, especially from drfrogsplat. 

In addition to using Icon Composer, I find that I prefer a utility from iDeveloper - "Icon Generator" to quickly make icons in every required size. It's in the Mac AppStore.

Comment: Apple sez, "There is no longer a 1024x1024 size. That’s replaced by 512x512@2x," and "Don’t use Icon Composer—it can’t create high-resolution icns files." ...and lastly, "Use iconutil to Create an icns File Manually
The iconutil command-line tool converts iconset folders to deployment-ready, high-resolution icns files. (You can find complete documentation for this tool by entering man iconutil in Terminal.)"

Comment: FYI: Icon Composer is no longer available in Additional Tools for Xcode 8.2

Answer (score 15):

What I found easier than downloading, installing, and finding Icon Composer was using the command-line tool `iconutil`.

1. Put your png files of each size into a folder. The folder must have the extension `.iconset`
2. Enter this command into the Terminal window:

   `iconutil -c icns <iconset filename>`

   where `<iconset filename>` is the path to the folder containing the set of pngs.
3. The output `.icns` file is written to the same location as the folder.

You must have the following set of pngs:

```
icon_16x16.png
icon_16x16@2x.png
icon_32x32.png
icon_32x32@2x.png
icon_128x128.png
icon_128x128@2x.png
icon_256x256.png
icon_256x256@2x.png
icon_512x512.png
icon_512x512@2x.png
```

Comment: What's the difference between, for example, icon_128x128.png and icon_128x128@2x.png?

Comment: @andrewrk apparently, that means the resolution of the image should be doubled (2x). So `icon_128x128@2x.png` should be 256x256.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison ok then what's the difference between icon_128x128@2x.png and icon_256x256.png?

Comment: @andrewrk: there is no difference in size. This can be verified by using `iconutil` on an `.icns` file and examining the images that result. (Though I'm not sure I understand why either.)

Comment: @NathanOsman the difference is UID. While a 128x128@2x may be technically able to display the same data as an 256x256@1x, the output would be a lot smaller on the 128 variant and as such a human looking at it may benefit from simplified graphics at 2x resolutions.

Answer (score 13):

Check out Icon Composer 2x. It's a replacement for Apple's Icon Composer that supports Retina Resolution Icons.

You can get it here: http://www.lemonmojo.com/work#IconComposer2x

I wrote the app, it's free and source code is available on Github if you're interested.

Answer (score 5):

I created a droplet that creates an icon from a PNG using applescript, here's the code:

```
    on open input
    repeat with input in input
        set inputalias to input as alias
        tell application "Finder"
            set inputname to name of inputalias
            set inputcontainer to container of inputalias
        end tell
        if inputname ends with ".png" then
            set foldername to ((text 1 through ((length of inputname) - 4) in inputname) & ".iconset") as text
            tell application "Finder"
                try
                    make new folder at inputcontainer with properties {name:foldername}
                end try
                set thefolder to folder foldername of inputcontainer
                set iconnames to "icon_16x16.png
icon_16x16@2x.png
icon_32x32.png
icon_32x32@2x.png
icon_128x128.png
icon_128x128@2x.png
icon_256x256.png
icon_256x256@2x.png
icon_512x512.png
icon_512x512@2x.png"
                set iconnames to paragraphs of iconnames
                repeat with iconname in iconnames
                    duplicate inputalias to thefolder with replacing
                    set iconfile to file inputname of thefolder
                    set name of iconfile to iconname

                end repeat
            end tell

            set folderpath to POSIX path of (thefolder as alias)
            do shell script "iconutil -c icns " & (quoted form of folderpath)
            display dialog ("Icon created for " & inputname) giving up after 10
            tell application "Finder" to delete thefolder
        else
            display dialog (inputname & " cannot be made into an icon. Please choose a PNG file.")
        end if
    end repeat
end open
```

Comment: For future on-lookers: step.1: open applescript step.2: copy and paste the code JoeFrizzell posted above. Step.3: save as .app Step.4: drag and drop your .png onto the .app you just created.