# How to extract keyboard layout icon

Tags: macos, icon, display, resources

I need to get those flag icons:

[image]

Question is **How do I do it?**

As far I've tried :

- searching the web for them (duh..),
- extracting them from [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) package (only non-retina ones are there),
- (Unsuccessfully) trying to extract it from this file: `/System/Library/Keyboard\ Layouts/AppleKeyboardLayouts.bundle/Contents/Resources/AppleKeyboardLayouts-L.dat`

Either pointing me to this resource or any hint on how to *"open"* this `.dat` file will be really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a Mac or an iOS a device?

Comment: Macbook Pro Retina on Yosemite (not sure if that's relevant).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `apple-kbd-dat-icon-extract.py` from https://github.com/phible/scripts:

`curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/phible/scripts/master/apple-kbd-dat-icon-extract.py -o a.py;mkdir icons;python a.py -o icons`

Comment: That's **exactly** what I was looking for! Live long and prosper, my friend :).